# ready.mobi mobile readiness nesting xsl tags appropriately?

Tags: xslt, coldfusion, xhtml, markup, nested

I've been trying to change my code for a while now and have failed to do so.

I am able to get the readiness score to peak at 3.72 and have the code display and function well here:
*link removed*

But when used with ready.mobi:
ready.mobi/launch.jsp?locale=en_EN#fragment-1

I get the following errors:

```
    FAIL near line -1 column -1
    Your page does not validate against XHTML Basic 1.1 or XHTML Mobile Profile 1.2

    FAIL near line 41 column 17
    The content of element type "a" must match "(br|span|em|strong|dfn|code|samp|kbd|var|cite|abbr|acronym|q|tt|i|b|big|small|sub|sup|img|object|input|select|textarea|label|button|script|noscript)".

    FAIL near line 46 column 17
    *same element type "a" error line

    FAIL near line 51 column 17
    *same element type "a" error line

    FAIL near line 56 column 17
    .....

    FAIL near line 61 column 17
    ...
```

Because of the markup errors, the xhtml mobile profile fails as well.

But having said that, my score can be a 5 with both xhtml mobile profile and markup valid if the code is like the following:
*link removed*

The nesting order is changed for the validator to accept. However, this causes the links to be broken.

Before:

```
    <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="p"><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>more</xsl:text></xsl:attribute><xsl:text>more...</xsl:text></xsl:element>
```

After:

```
    <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:element name="p"><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>more</xsl:text></xsl:attribute><xsl:text>more...</xsl:text></xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

Any help will be appreciated. :)
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you put the `<a>` inside the `<p>`?

```
<xsl:element name="p"><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>more</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:text>more...</xsl:text></xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

or much more simply, using literal result elements and an *attribute value template* for the `href`:

```
<p class="more"><a href="{link}">more...</a></p>
```

Comment: Yes!!! Both solution worked perfectly.

Thank you very much!! :))

I'm using element name=p and name=class with variable=more declarations to assign the css:

<p class="more">, but now that I use this code, the css styling has been removed.

Just trying to think where it went wrong now.

Comment: @user1792848 both "solutions" I propose should be identical, they're two different ways to express the same thing.  I generally find it clearer to use literal elements and attributes like `<p class="...">` whenever possible, and reserve `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attribute>` for the cases that can't be expressed literally, e.g. where the element/attribute name is calculated at runtime rather than fixed, or where I want to add/not add an attribute based on some condition.